# borderRadius property of TextInput not working in react-native.

Tags: react-native

I want to use rounded TextInput in my react-native application but when I am setting  its borderRadius property its not working. Suggest me way to do that.

```
    <TextInput  placeholder="Email" style={styles.textInput} />

    textInput:{

    borderColor:'black',
    backgroundColor:'#D3D3D3',
    width:300,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    fontSize:15,
    borderRadius: 25,

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply border on `View`, parent of `TextInput`

```
<View style={styles.borderStyle}>
 <TextInput  placeholder="Email" style={styles.textInput} />
</View>
```

Comment: I did it. But why borderRadius property in textInput does'nt work though it works on buttons in react-native?? @Shukarullah Shahh

Comment: Because borderRadius is View style property and it won't apply to textInput. 

Here is the official documentation, for style cheat sheet, it has good information on what style apply to what native elements

Answer (score 9):

Try `overflow:"hidden"` on the TextInput that has borderRadius.

Answer (score 3):

<TextInput
theme={{
roundness: 20 // try this
}}
/>

Answer (score 1):

Apply below code :

```
<TextInput
  style={{ height: 40, width: "95%", borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 20,  marginBottom: 20, fontSize: 18 }}
  // Adding hint in TextInput using Placeholder option.
  placeholder=" Enter Your First Name"
  // Making the Under line Transparent.
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of react native paper docs, they mention that you need to use outlineStyle to set border color and border-radius

```
outlineStyle
Type: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
Pass style to override the default style of outlined wrapper. Overrides style when mode is set to outlined Example: borderRadius, borderColor
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. You need to use the outlineStyle prop.

Example: `<Input outlineStyle={{borderRadius: 20}} />`

This works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Add theme={{roundness: 20}}
theme is a react native paper property

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

*f you are using React Native Paper, try this:

```
 <TextInput
    label="Enter the URL of the recipe you want to save"
    value={url}
    onChangeText={text => setUrl(text)}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    style={styles.input}
    mode="outlined"
    outlineStyle={{borderRadius: 50}}
  />
```